# break and switch appears to execute all case statements

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

In the latest stable release of Java and Eclipse (Kempler), entering the following code and executing it, assuming the package and class names exist:

```
package some_package;

public class what_the_heck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 2;
        int x = 1;
        switch(p){  
            case (1):
                x--;
            case (2):
                x = 2;
            case (3):
                x = 3;
            default:
                x++;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

This prints the value 4.  Originally, I thought it should print 2 because I thought that even if there were no break statements, each piece of code is still held in a case statement.  Now I think that the issue lies in how it is compiled.  For example, my current belief is that internally a boolean keeps track of whether or not a case statement was equal to the value.  If it was, then the boolean is true and *all case statements will be treated as true* until a break is found.  This makes sense, but I am still wondering if there are other reasons behind this, or if I am entirely wrong in my assumption.

Comment: "The code is intentionally missing break statements."  You answered your own question.

Comment: @ the OP: That is the behavior of the switch statement. You are free to creating your own Java compiler to alter that behavior.

Comment: Why didn't you bother to read the Java docs about switch statements?

Comment: To be fair, this fall through behavior of `switch` which was inherited from C, is indeed a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Btw your class name ShouldBeCamelCased as per java convention

Comment: @rgettman, I have edited my question to better suit my inquiry.  Sorry for the confusion.  I'm now looking for why the case statements are ignored and their code is executed after a single case statement is evaluated to true (when there are no break statements).  My current idea is in the question.

Comment: @fmsf It's not a real class, of course.  This is all done as an example (by the way, this code is from my friend and I did not check it - I guess I should have).  Edit as you want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why switch works as it does is that this:

```
switch(p){  
        case (1):
            x--;
        case (2):
            x = 2;
        case (3):
            x = 3;
        default:
            x++;
    }
```

is really just syntactic sugar for this (basically):

```
if (p == 1)
    goto .L1;
else if (p == 2)
    goto .L2;
else if (p == 3)
    goto .L3;
else
    goto .L4;

.L1:
    x--;
.L2:
    x = 2;
.L3:
    x = 3;
.L4:
    x++;
```

Java doesn't have a `goto` statement, but C does, and that's where it comes from. So if `p` is 2, it jumps to `.L2` and executes all the statements following that label.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't put a `break` the switch will execute all other cases that are underneath the entry point

So it actually executes

```
 x = 2;
 x = 3;
 x++;
 print(x);
 System.out.println(x);
```

Tks to [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) here is a [link to the specification of the switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

Comment: But why does it do this?  It should still read it as "if p == blah" before it tries to execute it (otherwise it wouldn't make much sense).  I guess it depends on how it is compiled.

Comment: it's like that by specification of the switch. It is how it was designed to work.

Comment: As always [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) holds the answer: "If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the expression, then we say that the case matches, and **all statements after the matching case label in the switch block, if any, are executed** in sequence." So if you want to stop this behaviour you need to place `break` at the end of each case.

Comment: Try not thinking of a `case` as a way of _isolating_ a block of code, but of giving it an _address_ that you can jump to.  Your switch says, if `p == 2`, then **go to the statement x = 2;** and resume execution.  It will continue executing every subsequent statement, and it does not care if those statements have their own addresses (`case` labels).  If you want to stop before you hit the next `case` label, you have to explicitly tell it to with a `break` or `continue` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If a condition in a case block is true and there is no `return` or `break`, all the other case blocks will be executed regardless if the are true or not.

For a rule of thumb always put a break or return at the end of a `case` block and you will be 90% right.

```
switch (p) {
    case (1):
        x--;
        break;
    case (2):
        x = 2;
        break;
    case (3):
        x = 3;
        break;
    default:
        x++;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip all following cases you need to put a `break;` at last of this case block or all following case blocks are executed, too.

Have a look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html